# Why do Iyengar brides sit in father's lap during the wedding ceremony?

Tags: rituals, sri-vaishnava, marriage, customs

In the South Indian Sri-Vaishnava community of Iyengars, there is a peculiar custom that the bride sits on her father's lap while tying the Mangalya sutra.

Such custom is not found in any other South Indian or other communities.

**What is the significance behind this?**

Comment: First of all there is no mention of tying the Mangala Sutra at all in Grihya Sutras, let alone sitting on the father's lap while tying.

Comment: it is not 'strange'. even a century ago, girls would get married before puberty, when they were kids, which is according to dharma-shastras. generally kids sit father's lap (right thigh). after marriage and coming of age, women are allowed to sit on husband's lap (left thigh). even during marriage ceremony such event takes place, where husband chants mantras while she is on his lap. so it is a symbolic transfer of kanya-daan - until now, father is her caretaker. after that it is husband. it may not be in gruhya sutras, but it is a traditional practice from days of early marriage.

Comment: This is not a Q about religion. Adding an afterthought such as "are there scriptural references" does not make it about religion. This is a cultural practice.

Comment: @moonstar2001 Marriage is a hindu samskara. Cultural practices comes under deshachara or kulachara.

Comment: @ram you can use those references of child marriage in your answer and write up a detailed answer.

Comment: If you acknowledge that it is desachara , why are you asking for scriptural references? This is a clear case of disingenuous use of this site.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I am not a iyengar so i m not sure if its deshachar or kulachar or not ? cos not other tamil people have such custom. So is there any text of their or some smritis which has some customs ?

Comment: Interesting custom. Is there any video on the web displaying this custom?